# LDA Topic Model Issue

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I doing some Text Mining exercises with twitter data. The original dataframe has 1280 rows. In order to avoid:

> Error in LDA(dtm_cea, k = 8) : 
>     Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry

I eliminate in the sparse matrix any row without entries:

```
rowTotals <- apply(dtm , 1, sum) 
dtm.new   <- dtm[rowTotals_cea> 0, ] 
lda <- LDA(dtm.new, k = 8)
topic <- topics(lda, 1)
```

Consequently my dtm.new lost a few rows; in fact the number of rows decreases to 1273.

The fact is that now I need to retrieve another column from the original dataframe (1280 rows) and rbind with topic (1273 rows), to make a chart. How can I identify, in the original data, which lines should be eliminated, due to the change made to the DTM?

Comment: Couldn't you use the same logic on your original dataframe that you've used to go from 1280 -> 1273 in your DTM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of which ones you're removing, or reconstruct the index used to remove them.

```
rowstokeep <- rowTotals > 0
newdataframe <- originaldataframe[rowstokeep, ]
```